# FFMPEG - how to stream video directly to HLS

Tags: java, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, shaka

We need to get video file/data as a stream from the user or from a caller to our API and while processing it we need to generate live stream using HLS

FFMPEG support creating live stream in HLS format with the following command

```
 String cmd[] = new String[]{
                "ffmpeg",
                "-re",
                "-i", src,
                "-c:v:0", "copy",
                "-b:v:1", "512k",
                "-b:a:0", "64k",
                "-b:a:1", "32k",
                "-map", "0:v",
                "-map", "0:a",
                "-map", "0:v",
                "-map", "0:a",
                "-f", "hls",
                "-var_stream_map", "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1",
                "-hls_time", "5",
                "-hls_segment_filename", folder+"/stream_%v/data%02d.ts",
                "-hls_list_size", "5",
                "-hls_delete_threshold", "2",
                "-hls_flags", "delete_segments",
                "-master_pl_name", "playlist.m3u8",
                folder+"/stream_%v/sub-playlist.m3u8"};
```

where the source can be

1. A file on disk  /path/file.mp4
2. A UDP url  udp://localhost:port

We are getting the bytes that we need to encode in a function like this:

```
handleFileStream(HttpServletRequest request)
```

and then we can loop the input stream and send it to FFMPEG using UDP

```
ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
int bytesRead;
 while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
     DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, bytesRead, address, udpCurPort);
     socket.send(packet);               
 }
```

but this method has 2 problems that we can see

1. we need to communicate with FFMPEG with udp and we need a new port for each conversion and we assume that we will have multiple conversions running simultaneously
2. we see that ffmpeg creates the HLS play list only at the end of the stream , and we what the stream to be created during the stream process

Is there a better way to pass streaming bytes to FFMPEG?

We are running inside a java environment and we launch FFMPEG like this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);
```